# Java - MongoDB Minimum Operator

Tags: java, mongodb, operators, minimum

I have tried to following to calculate the minimum in Java using the Java driver for MongoDB:

```
for (int i = 0; i < uniqueRegions.size(); i++) {
        BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("Region", uniqueRegions.get(i))
                                                .append("Year", new BasicDBObject("$min", "Year"));
        cursor = coll.find(query);
        try {
            while (cursor.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(uniqueRegions.get(i));
                System.out.println(cursor.next());
            }
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
```

However I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.mongodb.MongoException: Can't canonicalize query: BadValue unknown operator: $min
```

I've created a query with the `$min` operator isolated:

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("$min", "Year");
```

and it still generates the error so the problem is with how I'm using it. Can someone tell me the correct syntax to get this to work please.

Comment: isn't it '$min': "Year"

Comment: @madhawapriyashantha I tried that however it causes an error and the code doesn't compile.

Comment: [`$min`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/min/#grp._S_min) is an `aggregate` operator, not a `find` operator.

Comment: @JohnnyHK I've just come across find().min() however still can't get it to display, do you know how to make it work?

Comment: this $min doesn't do what you think it does.  if you want the smallest value of a field across documents then you need to aggregate and use $min operator in $group stage.